# How to add validation for telephone number in the format (xx) 10 numbers in address book in my account

Tags: magento2

I want to validate telephone number in the below format in my account address information page

```
 (2digits)10digits

 Ex : (56)1234567890
```

while saving data this format will be validate

Comment: Do you want to have formatted phone in edit customer address form input field or you want to format phone in address list?

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk I want to validation like this format in customer address while submit

Answer (score 0):

Depends on Magento version you can create following mixins

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```js
let config = {
    "config": {
        "mixins": {
            // Magento 2.4.4
            "Magento_Directory/js/region-updater": {
                "Acme_StackExchange/js/directory-region-updater-mixin": true
            },
            // Magento prior 2.4.4
            "Magento_Checkout/js/region-updater": {
                "Acme_StackExchange/js/region-updater-mixin": true
            },
            // extend validator
            'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
                'Oro_Rainbird/js/validator-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/web/js/validator-mixin.js`

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/validate'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function (validator) {
        validator.addRule('validate-phone-strict', function (v, e) {
            // your logic to verify
            v=v.replace(/\D+/g, '');
            if (v.length != 12) {
                return false;
            }
            // optional update input format
            $(e).val(v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{10})/g, '($1)$2'));

            return true;
        }, $.mage.__("Please enter a valid phone number. For example (99)1234567890."));
});
```

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/web/js/directory-region-updater-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    let widgetMixin = {
        _create: function () {
            this._super();

            let match = this.options.regionListId.match(/^(.*)region_id(.*?)$/);
            let selector = match[1] + 'telephone' + match[2];
            $(selector).addClass("validate-phone-strict");
            // optional if you use jquery mask
            //$(selector).mask("999-999-9999", {placeholder: '___-___-____'});
        }
    };

    return function (targetWidget) {
        $.widget('mage.directoryRegionUpdater', targetWidget, widgetMixin);
        return $.mage.directoryRegionUpdater;
    }
});
```

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/web/js/region-updater-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    let widgetMixin = {
        _create: function () {
            this._super();

            let match = this.options.regionListId.match(/^(.*)region_id(.*?)$/);
            let selector = match[1] + 'telephone' + match[2];
            $(selector).addClass("validate-phone-strict");
            // optional if you use jquery mask
            //$(selector).mask("999-999-9999", {placeholder: '___-___-____'});
        }
    };

    return function (targetWidget) {
        $.widget('mage.regionUpdater', targetWidget, widgetMixin);
        return $.mage.regionUpdater;
    }
});
```

Comment: am using magento2.4.3 version ...Can I use this code app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/web/js/validator-mixin.js